# How to find certain node in a BST based on a certain field and print those nodes entire attributes?

Tags: c

Another question about BSTs,

```
struct listing
{
    int id;
    char agent[12];
    int price;
    int size; //In square feet
    int numBeds;
    double numBaths;
    int yearBuilt;
    char address[ADD_LENGTH];
    struct listing *left;
    struct listing *right;
};

void findListingByPrice(struct listing *node, int maxPrice)
{
    if(node == NULL)
    {
        printf("This node does not exist in the database.");
        return;
    }
    else if(node->price < maxPrice)
    {
        //I'm stuck here.
    }
}
```

Alright, so my question is (hopefully it makes sense), how can I find the nodes with the price field that is less than maxPrice and print ONLY those nodes' fields out? Like if there were 3 nodes that had a price lower than maxPrice, I can only print the fields of those 3 nodes out. How do I do that? Thank you!

Comment: Is the tree built based on which value?

Answer (score 0):

You simply should do an inorder kind of traversal as it will give the price in sorted order, assuming you are constructing the tree by key as price.

```
void findListingByPrice(struct node *node, int maxPrice)
{
    if(node == NULL)
    {
        return;
    }else {
        findListingByPrice(node->left, maxPrice);
        if(node->price <=maxPrice) {
            printf("Found 1\n");
            print(node);
        }
        findListingByPrice(node->right, maxPrice);
    }
 
 
}
```

Visit [this](http://ideone.com/DTsgaD) link for the complete code.

Hope this helps you.

Comment: What would I do if the tree was constructed by a different field?

Comment: Then also the above thing will work because you are traversing the complete tree anyway. In case its made using price as a key, then you can stop traversing once you find a node with price greater than max price.